# Migration Command issue

Tags: artisan-migrate

Actually i am running PHP artisan migrate command on cmd to tun migration but there is nothing happen on my screen .The cursor is just blinking.

D:\D DRIVE\Yazdan\software\htdocs\new1_larval>php artisan migrate
^C
D:\D DRIVE\Yazdan\software\htdocs\new1_larval>

Comment: Please, can you extend your questions with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while command running.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will stop execution of command.